# Is 447 installs and 320 uninstalls Normal for a productivity app on google play store

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-console, google-developers-console

[image]

I’m new to app development and have released an app to google play console
I have a productivity focused application

Was wondering if getting 320 uninstalls on 477 installs normal

Searched on google but found nothing on the matter

Comment: What is "normal"?  Maybe this is just an indication that people think that your app is not useful, doesn't work, or something like that.

Comment: Mostly, the app retention ratio is between 25% and 35% for all my apps. so it's a normal thing.

Comment: This doesn't look like a programming question...

Answer (score 0):

Yes, any number would be normal there are millions of apps out there.